# SQL Server 2008: display time in hh:mm format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime-format

I have a time field in a table that I would like to display in a view in **hh:mm** format. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108)

RESULT:  13:19
```

For Time values

```
DECLARE @TimeField TIME = CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME);

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @TimeField, 108)

RESULT:  13:21
```

Answer (score 3):

And to do it by SQL:

```
SELECT FORMAT( getdate(), 'HH:mm', 'en-US' )
```

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: This works in SQL Server 2016, but the question is about 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest Code:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME), 108)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@Regdate,108),5)
```

**Or**

```
SELECT COUNT(Id)FROM Students Where CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),RegDate,108)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@Regdate,108)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) – hh:mm:ss
```

OR

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 113) – dd mon yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm
```